# Customize U-boot script to modify u-boot process

Tags: embedded-linux, u-boot

I am trying to customize the boot script which is used to boot my STM32MP157 Avenger96 board. I want to include some u-boot variables and alter the boot process.

Current boot script:

```
if test -n "${distro_bootpart}"; then
  setenv partition "${distro_bootpart}"
else
  setenv partition "${bootpart}"
fi

if test ! -e ${devtype} ${devnum}:${partition} boot/fitImage; then
  echo "This boot medium does not contain a suitable fitImage file for this system."
  echo "devtype=${devtype} devnum=${devnum} partition=${partition}  loadaddr=${loadaddr}"
  echo "Aborting boot process."
  exit 1
fi

part uuid ${devtype} ${devnum}:${partition} uuid

# Some STM32MP1-based systems do not encode the baudrate in the console variable
if test "${console}" = "ttySTM0" && test -n "${baudrate}"; then
  setenv console "${console},${baudrate}"
fi

if test -n "${console}"; then
  setenv bootargs "${bootargs} console=${console}"
fi

#New variables I want to include bootlimit rootfspart
setenv bootlimit 5
setenv rootfspart 4

setenv bootargs "${bootargs} root=PARTUUID=${uuid} rw rootwait consoleblank=0"

#Pass bootargs like this
setenv bootargs "${bootargs} root=/dev/mmcblk0p${rootfspart} rdinit=/bin/kinit rw  single\0"

load ${devtype} ${devnum}:${partition} ${loadaddr} boot/fitImage
if test $? != 0 ; then
  echo "Failed to load fitImage file for this system from boot medium."
  echo "devtype=${devtype} devnum=${devnum} partition=${partition}  loadaddr=${loadaddr}"
  echo "Aborting boot process."
  exit 2
fi

# A custom script exists to load DTOs
if test -n "${loaddtoscustom}" ; then
  # Pull DTOs from fitImage and manually apply them to base DT
  if test -n "${loaddtos}" ; then
    # Matches UBOOT_DTB_LOADADDRESS in OE layer machine config
    setexpr loadaddrdtb 0xcff00000
    # Matches UBOOT_DTBO_LOADADDRESS in OE layer machine config
    setexpr loadaddrdtbo 0xcff80000

    setexpr loaddtossep gsub '#conf' ' fdt' "${loaddtos}"
    setexpr loaddtb 1

    for i in ${loaddtossep} ; do
      if test ${loaddtb} = 1 ; then
        echo "Using base DT ${i}"
        imxtract ${loadaddr} ${i} ${loadaddrdtb} ;
        fdt addr ${loadaddrdtb}
        fdt resize
        setenv loaddtb 0
      else
        echo "Applying DTO ${i}"
        imxtract ${loadaddr} ${i} ${loadaddrdtbo} ;
        fdt apply ${loadaddrdtbo}
      fi
    done

    setenv loaddtb
    setenv loaddtossep
    setenv loadaddrdtbo
    setenv loadaddrdtb
  fi

  # Run the custom DTO loader script
  #
  # In case 'loaddtos' variable is set, then the 'fdt' command is already
  # configured to point to a DT, on top of which all the DTOs present in
  # the fitImage and selected by the 'loaddtos' are applied. Hence, the
  # user is now free to apply any additional custom DTOs loaded from any
  # other source.
  #
  # In case 'loaddtos' variable is not set, the 'loaddtoscustom' script
  # must configure the 'fdt' command to point to the custom DT.
  run loaddtoscustom
  if test -z "${bootm_args}" ; then
    setenv bootm_args "${loadaddr} - ${fdtaddr}"
  fi
else
   setenv bootm_args "${loadaddr}${loaddtos}"
fi

echo "Booting the Linux kernel..." \
&& bootm ${bootm_args}
```

Now I want to add `bootlimit` and `rootfspart` to above script and also to pass `bootargs` as `setenv bootargs "${bootargs} root=/dev/mmcblk0p${rootfspart} rdinit=/bin/kinit rw single\0"`.

The config file is in `include/configs/dh_stm32mp1.h`:

```
#ifndef __CONFIG_DH_STM32MP1_H__
#define __CONFIG_DH_STM32MP1_H__

#include <configs/stm32mp1.h>

#define CONFIG_BOOTCOUNT_LIMIT
#define CONFIG_BOOTCOUNT_ENV

#define CONFIG_SPL_TARGET               "u-boot.itb"
#undef STM32MP_BOOTCMD
#define STM32MP_BOOTCMD "bootcmd_stm32mp=" \
        "if run load_bootenv; then run importbootenv;fi;" \
        "echo \"Boot over ${boot_device}${boot_instance}!\";" \
        "if test ${boot_device} = serial || test ${boot_device} = usb;" \
        "then stm32prog ${boot_device} ${boot_instance}; " \
        "else " \
                "run env_check;" \
                "if test ${boot_device} = mmc;" \
                "then env set boot_targets \"mmc${boot_instance}\"; fi;" \
                "if test ${boot_device} = nand ||" \
                  " test ${boot_device} = spi-nand ;" \
                "then env set boot_targets ubifs0; fi;" \
                "run distro_bootcmd;" \
        "fi;\0"

#undef CONFIG_EXTRA_ENV_SETTINGS
#define CONFIG_EXTRA_ENV_SETTINGS \
        "bootdelay=1\0" \
        "bootlimit=5\0" \
        "rootfspart=4\0" \
        "bootargs=root=/dev/mmcblk0p${rootfspart} rdinit=/bin/kinit rw single\0" \
        "kernel_addr_r=0xc2000000\0" \
        "fdt_addr_r=0xc4000000\0" \
        "scriptaddr=0xc4100000\0" \
        "pxefile_addr_r=0xc4200000\0" \
        "splashimage=0xc4300000\0"  \
        "ramdisk_addr_r=0xc4400000\0" \
        /*"altbootcmd=run bootcmd\0" \ */
        "env_default=1\0" \
        "env_check=if test $env_default -eq 1;"\
                " then env set env_default 0;env save;fi\0" \
        STM32MP_BOOTCMD \
        BOOTENV \
        "altbootcmd=" \
        "  echo Rollback to previous RootFs; " \
        "  if test ${rootfspart} = 4; " \
        "    then setenv rootfspart 5; " \
        "  else " \
        "     setenv rootfspart 4; " \
        "  fi; setenv bootcount 0; saveenv; " \
        "  bootcmd\0" \
        "boot_net_usb_start=true\0" \
        "usb_pgood_delay=1000\0" \
        "update_sf=" /* Erase SPI NOR and install U-Boot from SD */     \
               "setexpr loadaddr1 ${loadaddr} + 0x1000000 && "         \
               "load mmc 0:4 ${loadaddr1} /boot/u-boot-spl.stm32 && "  \
               "env set filesize1 ${filesize} && "                     \
               "load mmc 0:4 ${loadaddr} /boot/u-boot.itb && "         \
               "sf probe && sf erase 0 0x200000 && "                   \
               "sf update ${loadaddr1} 0 ${filesize1} && "             \
               "sf update ${loadaddr1} 0x40000 ${filesize1} && "       \
               "sf update ${loadaddr} 0x80000 ${filesize} && "         \
               "env set filesize1 && env set loadaddr1\0" \
        "load_bootenv="\
        "usb stop; usb start; if load usb ${usbdev}:${usbpart} ${loadaddr}  DHupdate.ini;" \
        "then echo \"--> Update: found DHupdate.ini (${filesize} bytes)\"; fi;\0"\
        "importbootenv=echo Importing environment from DHupdate.ini...; env import -t      ${loadaddr} ${filesize}\0"\
        "usbdev=0\0"\
        "usbpart=1\0"
#endif
```

I have also included `bootlimit` and `rootfspart` and passed `bootargs` in above file. My question is:

1. Do I need to again define these variables in the config file?
2. Also, I want to use `altbootcmd` like above. Is this correct? Will the above modifications work?
3. After these changes I bitbaked the u-boot recipe and bitbaked the image recipe and copied the file to SD card and booted from it. But when I do `fw_printenv rootfspart` or `fw_printenv bootlimit` I cannot see the set values or it returned empty.
4. And also how are the variables like '${distro_bootpart} `and '${devtype}` set in boot script? From where are these variables accessed?

Can anyone please let me know what am I doing wrong and how to make this work?

Your help will be much appreciated.

Thanks in advance.

P.S: I am new to U-boot and learning to use it. I am using Yocto as build system with Ubuntu 20.04. Please let me know if you need any further info.